# Save text on XML file or Database

Tags: xml, database, performance, prestashop

I'm working partime for an company and my boss ask me to make an module for `PrestaShop` to read/write news ( only Text ) into a `XML` file. But i think load text form XML will be slowly.

Anybody can tell me save text in XML file or Database, which better and why??

Thanks. :)

Comment: Is it one text at once or one million texts at once? Because if its just one, using database won't improve anything.

Answer (score 2):

If the requeriments of news just involve text, i would prefer the Database Approach for storing, and XML as a way of transmitting data. The RDBMS are smart enough to handle text data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we're talking about a small number of text entries since this is a news feed for an eCommerce site.

Given that assumption, you will probably not see a performance hit either way.

One advantage of XML is that you could format the XML as an [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) and then use the RSS feed for other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the items to a file, there will be a lot of XML parsing and file I/O you'll need to handle yourself. If you save the individual news items in a database, the database will handle the I/O for you (probably much better than you could do yourself). If you need the news items in XML format for some reason, store them as XML in the database; most modern enterprise-class RDBMSs offer a native XML data type and some pretty good functionality for transforming the XML as needed.